# An akka streams function that creates a sink and a source that emits whatever the sink receives

Tags: scala, websocket, akka-stream, akka-http

The goal is to implement a function with this signature

```
def bindedSinkAndSource[A]:(Sink[A, Any], Source[A, Any]) = ???
```

where the returned source emits whatever the sink receives.

My primary goal is to implement a websocket forwarder by means of the  [handleWebSocketMessages](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.4.10/scala/http/routing-dsl/directives/websocket-directives/handleWebSocketMessages.html#handlewebsocketmessages) directive.
The forwarder graph is:

```
leftReceiver ~> rightEmitter
leftEmitter <~ rightReceiver
```

where the `leftReceiver` and `leftEmiter` are the in and out of the left endpoint handler flow; and `rightReceiver` and `rightEmitter` are the in and out of the right endpoint handler flow.

For example:

```
import akka.NotUsed
import akka.http.scaladsl.model.ws.Message
import akka.http.scaladsl.server.Directive.addByNameNullaryApply
import akka.http.scaladsl.server.Directives._
import akka.http.scaladsl.server.Route
import akka.stream.scaladsl.Flow
import akka.stream.scaladsl.Sink
import akka.stream.scaladsl.Source

def buildHandlers(): Route = {
    val (leftReceiver, rightEmitter) = bindedSinkAndSource[Message];
    val (rightReceiver, leftEmitter) = bindedSinkAndSource[Message];

    val leftHandlerFlow = Flow.fromSinkAndSource(leftReceiver, leftEmitter)
    val rightHandlerFlow = Flow.fromSinkAndSource(rightReceiver, rightEmitter)

    pathPrefix("leftEndpointChannel") {
        handleWebSocketMessages(leftHandlerFlow)
    } ~
        pathPrefix("rightEndpointChannel") {
            handleWebSocketMessages(rightHandlerFlow)
        }
}
```

All the ideas that came to me were frustrated by the fact that the`handleWebSocketMessages(..)` directive don't give access to the materialized value of the received flow.

Comment: You can use GraphStage
, http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.4.10/scala/stream/stream-customize.html

Comment: @gaston, I tried with that, but I didn't figure out how. As far as I know, the resulting shape depends on the type and number of ports. And I found no way to bind two graph stages without ports in between. Could you send me a hint?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a way to achieve the goal, but there could be shorter and easier ways. If you know one, please don't hesitate to add your knowledge.

```
import org.reactivestreams.Publisher
import org.reactivestreams.Subscriber
import org.reactivestreams.Subscription

import akka.NotUsed
import akka.stream.scaladsl.Sink
import akka.stream.scaladsl.Source

def bindedSinkAndSource[A]: (Sink[A, NotUsed], Source[A, NotUsed]) = {

    class Binder extends Subscriber[A] with Publisher[A] { binder =>
        var oUpStreamSubscription: Option[Subscription] = None;
        var oDownStreamSubscriber: Option[Subscriber[_ >: A]] = None;
        var pendingRequestFromDownStream: Option[Long] = None;
        var pendingCancelFromDownStream: Boolean = false;

        def onSubscribe(upStreamSubscription: Subscription): Unit = {
            this.oUpStreamSubscription match {
                case Some(_) => upStreamSubscription.cancel // rule 2-5
                case None =>
                    this.oUpStreamSubscription = Some(upStreamSubscription);
                    if (pendingRequestFromDownStream.isDefined) {
                        upStreamSubscription.request(pendingRequestFromDownStream.get)
                        pendingRequestFromDownStream = None
                    }
                    if (pendingCancelFromDownStream) {
                        upStreamSubscription.cancel()
                        pendingCancelFromDownStream = false
                    }
            }
        }

        def onNext(a: A): Unit = {
            oDownStreamSubscriber.get.onNext(a)
        }

        def onComplete(): Unit = {
            oDownStreamSubscriber.foreach { _.onComplete() };
            this.oUpStreamSubscription = None
        }

        def onError(error: Throwable): Unit = {
            oDownStreamSubscriber.foreach { _.onError(error) };
            this.oUpStreamSubscription = None
        }

        def subscribe(downStreamSubscriber: Subscriber[_ >: A]): Unit = {
            assert(this.oDownStreamSubscriber.isEmpty);
            this.oDownStreamSubscriber = Some(downStreamSubscriber);

            downStreamSubscriber.onSubscribe(new Subscription() {
                def request(n: Long): Unit = {
                    binder.oUpStreamSubscription match {
                        case Some(usSub) => usSub.request(n);
                        case None =>
                            assert(binder.pendingRequestFromDownStream.isEmpty);
                            binder.pendingRequestFromDownStream = Some(n);
                    }
                };
                def cancel(): Unit = {
                    binder.oUpStreamSubscription match {
                        case Some(usSub) => usSub.cancel();
                        case None =>
                            assert(binder.pendingCancelFromDownStream == false);
                            binder.pendingCancelFromDownStream = true;
                    }
                    binder.oDownStreamSubscriber = None
                }
            })
        }
    }

    val binder = new Binder;
    val receiver = Sink.fromSubscriber(binder);
    val emitter = Source.fromPublisher(binder);
    (receiver, emitter);
}
```

Note that the instance vars of the `Binder` class may suffer concurrency problems if the sink and source this method creates are not fused later by the user. If that is not the case, all the accesses to these variables should be enclosed inside synchronized zones. Another solution would be to ensure that the sink and the source are materialized in an execution context with a single thread.

Two days later I discovered MergeHub and BroadcastHub. Using them the answer is much shorter:

```
import akka.stream.Materializer
def bindedSinkAndSource[T](implicit sm: Materializer): (Sink[T, NotUsed], Source[T, NotUsed]) = {
  import akka.stream.scaladsl.BroadcastHub;
  import akka.stream.scaladsl.MergeHub;
  import akka.stream.scaladsl.Keep;

  MergeHub.source[T](perProducerBufferSize = 8).toMat(BroadcastHub.sink[T](bufferSize = 256))(Keep.both) run
}
```

with the advantage that the returned sink and source can be materialized multiple times.